# How to initiate a message box result in app.xaml.cs, but retrieve the result on another .xaml.cs page

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, messagebox

On the _Activated event in app.xaml.cs I want to initiate a messagebox with a result on the app.xaml.cs page under application activated, but to retrieve the result on a different page. I can do the former just not the latter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure initiating a `MessageBox` in `App.xaml.cs` is a good practice, but if you really need to do so, you could just store the result in a variable of the `App` class. You will then be able to read that variable from any page.